# Method GetListItems from sharepoint webservice not working as expected

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint list and I need to get its items through the exposed webservice using the `GetListItems` method.

It worked fine until the number of items in the list reached 2005 (I discovered the problem at 2005, it might have happened a bit earlier, maybe at 2000 if we like round numbers)

The list I use has a default view "My items" which is supposed to filter items according to `me`, and I need some extra filtering on a column that contains a reference to a week.

Here a re the parameters I use:

- listName: `{E5FDF537-0A1F-47F7-BFEE-0922B5F6ED20}`
- viewName: `null` (gives exact same result with real view id).
- query: `<Where><Eq><FieldRef
  Name="Week" /><Value
  Type="Text">2011-W12</Value></Eq></Where>`
- viewFields: `null`
- rowLimit: `null`
- queryOptions: `<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>`
- webId: `null`

The problem is that I get the items as if the filter on `me` was not present, and if I try do do it by myself (with `<UserID Type=\"Integer\" />`), I just get no items (no errors, just no items).

Comment: I am wondering if this is a limit in the underlying query. Are even simple queries failing on this list? Are you able to delete entries and have the queries start working again?

Comment: It does not seem to depend on the complexity of the query. I also forgot to mention that on the real Sharepoint portal, there is no problem.
However, by tweaking the query, we finally managed to make it working, but I have no reliable explanation to the problem.

Comment: I think that just means that sharepoint didn't like your query for some reason (caml was invalid?).

Comment: Yes, Kit, probably. But in this case, I would have expected an error!